# Sympy Troubleshooting: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' and 'NegativeOne'

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, physics, chemistry

I'm trying to determine the entropy of adsorbed hydrogen gas, leaving the temperature "T" as a symbolic variable in Python using the sympy library, and am running into issues as a result

Originally, the process was completed numerically, which required my use of numpy to create a list of floating-point numbers. When I later decided to have the temperature be a variable, rather than a fixed value, I employed sympy to accomplish this. I get the following error as a result, relating to my use of a negative number within the exponent. Any advice would be appreciated. See code beloW:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym

c = 3e8
h = 6.626e-34
k = 1.38e-23

T = sym.symbols('T')

v = np.array([3034.1, 3027, 1265.8, 1257.5, 840.6, 642.7])
f=v*c*100

Q = sym.exp(-(h * f)/(2 * k * T))/(1 - (sym.exp(-(h * f))/(k * T)))
print(Q)
```

Comment: Don't mix `numpy` and `sympy` - at least not without real understanding of how they work, or don't work together.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, I am sure there could be issues there. I am unsure of how to write that list without using numpy. A list of integers, when applied, gives the error "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type "float". Furthermore, sympy does not have an "array" attribute as far as I know. So I am otherwise unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: What do you want `Q` to be?  A different expression for each element of `v`?  And yes, `[1,2,3]*3.4` is not going to work since `*` for a list means something quite different.

Comment: @hpaulj I would like Q to be a list of the same length as v, where each element of v is first multipled by the floating point numbers, then mathematically manipulated according to Q. For this stat. mech. code, the elements of Q will eventually be multiplied together and then differentiated with respect to T.

Comment: Make `f` a symbol, and get a "simple" sympy expression for `Q`.  Then use `subs` (in a list comprehension) to get an expression for each value in `v`.  Now you have a list of expressions when you can further calculate with.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for the suggestion. I have applied the solution which Oscar suggested below, and it seems to be working. With that said, I will take your advice into account for future coding problems.

Comment: Oscar's answer is exactly what I had in mind.  There's another tool for using numpy with sympy, `sympy.lambdify`, but that only works if you replace all symbols with numbers.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for sharing that bit of information, I'll look into that tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be clear when mixing numpy and sympy where you are using numpy arrays and where you are using symbolic expressions. Here is some code that does that:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym

c = 3e8
h = 6.626e-34
k = 1.38e-23

T = sym.symbols('T')

# We will substitute values from v_arr in place of v_sym
v_sym = sym.symbols('v')
v_arr = np.array([3034.1, 3027, 1265.8, 1257.5, 840.6, 642.7])

# Make a symbolic expression involving v_sym:
f = v_sym*c*100
Q = sym.exp(-(h * f)/(2 * k * T))/(1 - (sym.exp(-(h * f))/(k * T)))

# Substitute values from the numpy array into the symbolic expression:
Q_arr = [Q.subs(v_sym, v_val) for v_val in v_arr]

print(Q_arr)
```

Someone who understands the code will immediately spot something: there is absolutely no benefit in using numpy here and `v_arr` might as well be a list. You could also use a sympy Matrix instead of a numpy array but at least for the code as shown it does not offer any particular benefit.

Comment: Thank you Oscar, I appreciate the clear explanation of the issue. This seems to have resolved my problem.